# Can i use fscanf taking stdout as FILE stream?

Tags: c, file-io

I want to get the content of stdout.
Can I use the following snippet, or its wrong?

```
FILE *fd;
char a;
fd = fopen("filename","wa+");

// if statement to check if fd is NULL or not
// then :

do
{
    fscanf(stdout,"%c",&a);
    fprintf(fd,"%c",a); 
} while(a!=EOF);
```

Comment: Since _stdout_ is an **output** path, not an input path, you cannot perform input on it. In some situations, input on it might work however that can not be relied on and is undefined behaviour.

Comment: But since `stdout` is a file desc, like any other file desc shouldn't it work? Or is there another way? Maybe by using `read()` ?

Comment: Do you want to capture the `stdout` of another process? Then pipe it into your program, where you can read it from `stdin`.

Comment: It may "work," as in it'll compile and execute, but most operating systems won't support it in any meaningful way. Because there's nothing to read, it'll generally return immediately or hang.

Comment: No, what I wanna do is:
after opening the file. i have to run some instructions and call some external functions and capture the output of these in the file and close it.

Comment: @aro: If you say "external functions", do you mean library functions, or do you mean `system()`-like calling of executables? (This is called XY-problem: You are asking for a solution to Y, but your *problem* is X. Your question should be, "how do I capture the output of external functions"...)

Comment: Why are you using `fscanf` to read a single character?  `man fgetc`

Comment: `fd` is a terrible name for a file pointer.  The name `fd` implies that it is a file descriptor.  A file descriptor is an int, and a `FILE *` has an underlying file descriptor with can be obtained via `fileno`.

Answer (score 0):

Following snipped should do the trick. Create a pipe connected to stdout and read from it:

```
int fds[2];
pipe(fds);
dup2(fds[1], stdout);
fscanf(fds[0],"%c",&a);
```

Comment: I can't use `dup` or `dup2`. Nor can i use `freopen`. Isn't there any other way?